# Module not found?

Tags: node.js, express, render

while deploying the Node api in **render** i got this error  [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/config/coudinary.js' imported from /opt/render/project/src/controller/catagoriesController.js
but my localhost is working absolutely without any warnings and errors.

here’s build command

[Package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7df4P.png)

[hare is my folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Eu2.png)
How can I solve this error

Comment: How do you ```export``` and ```import``` modules? show some codes.